# Flutter facebook login with AWS cognito user pool Facebook review rejected

Tags: flutter, facebook, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook, flutter-facebook-login

I am trying to build a Flutter application for android and ios. I am using the flutter web sign-in for Facebook and google sign-in. But when I am submitting the application to Facebook for review it says you are providing a website as a review but you are using the Mobile application for the Facebook login. I am using AWS Cognito web as an authentication method for Facebook login.

Also tried this [https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter/) implementation but no luck.

Does anyone suggest how to proceed with this issue?